# How to add a second domain name under azurewebsites.net for an Azure App Service application?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a web app deployed to Azure App Services. It has a standard domain name under azurewebsites.net. Let's assume it's my-app.azurewebsites.net.

I now need to register a second domain pointing to the same environment. It would be something like alias-to-my-app.azurewebsites.net.

I don't want to use a custom domain. I want the alias to be a subdomain under azurewebsites.net. Is there a way to achieve this in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

After contacting Microsoft's support, I was informed that this is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this to be currently possible. The azurewebsites.net hostname is based on the name of the App Service, for which you can only have one.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a external domain under settings > custom domains or an another deployment slot.